# IPython Notebook Define a LaTeX macro both for mathjax and pdf conversion

Tags: latex, jupyter-notebook, mathjax

E.g., I have this `Markdown` cell that use the sanctioned way of using a `LaTeX` macro in the notebook

```
$\def\abc{a\,b\,c}$ The first three letters are $\abc$.
```

and I have what I want in the notebook. OTOH, when I "*Download as PDF via LaTeX*"
the conversion process fails with these errors in the standard error of the console

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.229 ...c{a\,b\,c}\) The first letters are \(\abc
                                                  \).
?
! Emergency stop.
l.229 ...c{a\,b\,c}\) The first letters are \(\abc
                                                  \).
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produce
Transcript written on notebook.log.
```

because `Latex` itself doesn't accept a definition embedded in a mathematical expression. Because `Markdown` doesn't accept these definitions outside a mathematical expression I feel like I'm trapped in a Comma 22 situation.

I'm pretty sure the system can be fooled using `Raw NBconvert` cells and smart latex code but I'm missing some step in my head... Any help will be properly appreciated, ciao

Answer (score 0):

The definition is accepted in the mathematics, but in TeX, definitions are localized to the nearest enclosing group.  Math delimiters are enclosing groups, so the definition is remove after the math.  Try using `\gdef` instead of `\def` to get a global definition.  This will require that you load the `begingroup` extension in MathJax, so you will have to add that to the configuration (I don't know how that is done in IPython, though).